# Excel 2007 - 13 Changing sheets to one master sheet

Tags: excel-2007

Ok Hi everybody,

I've been looking into this and trying to figure it out for a couple days now. I've found things close but nothing matches what I need.

I have 13 departments here and each department has a sheet with issues that need to be resolved.  What I need is when each of those departments updates their excel sheet with an issue it updates on the master list (which is in the same workbook). Since people are constantly deleting and adding the formula would need to stay.

Would it be easier to have them enter the data on the master sheet and have that go into the individual files? If so how would I even do that? Thanks in advance.  I'm trying to see if an advance filter or something would work but can't get it just right.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the names in my code but if you paste this code in each of your department sheets (not the master list) you should get your desired result:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlws = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To 13

    If IsEmpty(xlws.Cells(2, i).Value) = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next

Dim xlwsMaster As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlwsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master list")

i = 1

Do While IsEmpty(xlwsMaster.Range("A" & i).Value) = False
    i = i + 1
Loop


xlws.Range("A2:M2").Copy

xlwsMaster.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

xlws.Range("A2:M2").Clear

End Sub
```

every time there is a change on one of those sheets it will check to see if all the values of a through m are filled if they are it copies a2:m2 and pastes it at the first empty row on the master list and then clears a2:m2 on the sheet in question

Comment: Thank you soooo much Tbizzness, I just started here and found out they don't want/use macros however.  I apologize for the time wasted!

Comment: I know this is old and sorry for my newbness but what in your code would I have to change to match my sheets? Also if I didn't want it to clear the data on the subsheet would I just take out the "xlws.Range("a2:M2").Clear" ?

Comment: Yes remove the clear, but you will need to insert a new row at 2 because this works under the understanding that new data will always go in a2:m2.  The only code you should have to change is to set xlwsMaster equal to whatever your master sheet is called.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I'm pasting it and editing but apparently this is all too advanced for me.  The master list is actually called "Master List" and the data that the production lines input start at A2 and end at M2 but can go down as far as A64 and M64, probably even higher.  One of the sheets im pasting it into is "Autoline" if that helps.

Comment: is the data that is being put on the "Master List" added manually or automatically?

Comment: The data being put on "master list" will be coming automatically from one of the subsheets. The subsheets are manually typed in. I was able to piece together a simple macro that used just the last line used but now it needs to be more.  What needs to happen is if a previous issue complete they update it on the subsheet it needs to find that that row on the master list and updates it accordingly. We will have designations per production line; just A1, B1, etc etc. Where the letter is the production line and the number is the issue number.